# Why the Graph of the function $f(x)=\frac{x^2-3x+2}{x^2+2x-3}$ has not excluded $\frac{-1}{4}$ from the Range

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, graphing-functions

I was trying to find range of the function :

$$f(x)=\frac{x^2-3x+2}{x^2+2x-3}$$

we have the Domain as:

$$D_f=\mathbb{R}-\left\{-3,1\right\}$$

We have $$y=f(x)=\frac{(x-1)(x-2)}{(x+3)(x-1)}=\frac{x-2}{x+3}\tag{1}$$

So we get:

$$x=\frac{3y+2}{1-y}$$

so $y \ne 1$ Also when $x=1$ in Equation $(1)$ we get $y=\frac{-1}{4}$

Since $x=1$ is not in domain we exclude $y=\frac{-1}{4}$ in range.

hence range is $$D_r=\mathbb{R}-\left\{1,\frac{-1}{4}\right\}$$

But when I draw the graph of $$f(x)=\frac{x^2-3x+2}{x^2+2x-3}$$ in Desmos, why the value $\frac{-1}{4}$ is not excluded in range?

Comment: Is this a maths question, or is this a Desmos question?

Comment: (1) is true *if* $x\neq 1$ (you can simplify IF $x\neq 1$)

Comment: Left and right limits at $x=1$ exist, though the function is not defined at this point. So, consider the graph to have a hole at $(1,-1/4)$ (though the single point is not visible on desmos graph).